# How to store key-value pairs in Redis with erlang and then access that store with php?

Tags: php, erlang, redis

I'm new to redis, I'm storing a list in redis through erlang but I want to access that list from another server through php... is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be a problem - just make your redis instance available over the network rather than just localhost. That should just require a small change to redis.conf and configuring your firewall to allow requests on 6379. It's unsecured, so don't open it up completely.

You'll also need to make sure you aren't using a library that controls key naming internally -  not sure about php or erlang specifically, but some libraries build more complex structures on top of redis that would be much harder to use across multiple platforms.